# Ractive isn't capturing a change from jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, ractivejs

I'm using jquery-ui's datepicker with a Ractive template, and the two-way binding doesn't seem to be working properly.

My input looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{value}}" decorator="picker">
```

Then I'm instantiating the date picker through the "picker" decorator:

```
decorators: {
            picker: function(node) {
                $(node).datepicker();
                return {
                    teardown: function() {
                        $(node).datepicker("destroy");
                    }
                };  
            },
        }
```

The datepicker shows up perfectly, but value doesn't get updated properly.  If I through and observer on {{value}} I see that Ractive doesn't think the value has changed once it's been set by the datepicker.  If I click into the field, and back off again (losing focus), the observer triggers, and the value is set.

In my decorator I can setup a callback to trigger using the datepickers "onSelect" event, but how do I force a ractive change event from the decorator function?

```
decorators: {
    picker: function(node) {
        $(node).datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateValue) {
                    console.log("datevalue set");
                    //I've tried this already
                    $(node).change();
                    //and
                    $(node).trigger("change");
                    //neither work
                }
        });
        return {
            teardown: function() {
                $(node).datepicker("destroy");
            }
        };  
    },
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the decorator function, `this` refers to the current ractive instance, so you can call `ractive.updateModel()` to let it know the model needs to be updated based on the view:

```
decorators: {
    picker: function(node) {
        var ractive = this
        $(node).datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateValue) {
                    ractive.updateModel()
                }
        });
        return {
            teardown: function() {
                $(node).datepicker("destroy");
            }
        };  
    },
}
```

(See http://jsfiddle.net/arcca09t/)

---

### Edited

The current version of ractive use the as-* convention for decorators, you should edit the html like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{value}}" as-picker>
```

Answer (score 1):

ractive no longer uses decorator attributes like that.  But martypdx's suggestion sent me in the right direction.

```js
$(function(){
  var r = new Ractive({
      el: document.body,
      template: '#template',
      data: {
          value: null
      },
      decorators: {
          picker: function(node) {
              var ractive = this
              $(node).datepicker({
                  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                  onSelect: function(dateValue) {
                          ractive.updateModel()
                      }
              });
              return {
                  teardown: function() {
                      $(node).datepicker("destroy");
                  }
              };  
          },
      }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ractive@0.9.5/ractive.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    value: {{value}}
    <br>
    <input type="date" value="{{value}}" as-picker>
</script>
```

Comment: This is the current attribute convention but I think is better if you propose edition on previous answer which is still correct :)